# For $1<p<2, $ Fourier transform is not onto $L^p(\Bbb T) \to \ell^q(\Bbb Z)$ where $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1$

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, operator-theory, lp-spaces, fourier-transform

> For $1<p<2$ , Fourier transform $\mathscr{F}$ is not onto $L^p(\Bbb T) \to \ell^q(\Bbb Z)$ where $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1$

For $1 \le p \le 2$, Hausdorff-Young inequality implies that $\mathscr{F}:L^p(\Bbb T) \to \ell^q(\Bbb Z)$ where $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1$

Now for $p=1$ showing that $\mathscr{F}:L^1(\Bbb T) \to \ell^\infty(\Bbb Z)$ is not onto was easy due to Riemann-Lebesgue lemma (I know that it's image is in fact a dense sub-alegbra of $c_0(\Bbb Z)$).

But for $1<p<2$, I'm facing difficulty to show that it's not onto. I know that $\forall 1<p<2, \mathscr{F}(L^p(\Bbb T))\subset \ell^q(\Bbb Z)$ . Hence we have $$\mathscr{F}(L^p(\Bbb T))\subset \ell^q(\Bbb Z) \subsetneq c_0(\Bbb Z)$$ Also considering images of trigonometric polynomials under $\mathscr{F}$ we get that $c_{00}(\Bbb Z) \subsetneq \mathscr{F}(L^p(\Bbb T)$

So basically the scenario is, $$c_{00}(\Bbb Z) \subsetneq \mathscr{F}(L^p(\Bbb T)) \subset \ell^q(\Bbb Z) \subsetneq c_0(\Bbb Z)$$
How to produce an $\ell^q$ sequence which cannot be in the image of $\mathscr{F}$ ? Or if there are other functional analysis proofs which will assert the same?

Comment: take $S=\sum_{n \ge 1} \frac{\cos (2^nx)}{\sqrt n}$; it is obvious that the coefficients are in $l^q(\mathbb Z), q>2$ but it is a classic exercise that $S$ is not a Fourierseries (since the partial sums are not summable ae for any reasonable summation method like Caesaro or Abel, while Fourier series are summable ae)

Comment: @Conrad Sorry but I don't know what a Fourier-Stieltjes series is

Comment: Fourier series of measures on the unit circle (so if the measures are absolutely continuous wr Lebesgue they are usual Fourier series, but for example one can take the Fourier series of the Dirac measure) - I edited the original comment to talk only about Fourier series but as noted $S$ is not the Fourier series even in the more gneral measure sense

Comment: @Conrad I can understand your first comment now. I'll try to prove that the series you gave is not Abel summable. But it could be nice had you posted it as an answer so that I could close the question by accepting your answer

Comment: added the above as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $S=\sum_{n \ge 1} \frac{\cos (2^nx)}{\sqrt n}$. Note that the coefficients of $S$ are in $l^q(\mathbb Z)$ for all $q>2$ (but not in $l^2$!)

Then one can show that the partial series of $S$ and the Caesaro means of said partial series diverge ae on the unit circle so $S$ cannot be a Fourier series. Actually it is easier to show that the partial series/Caesaro means are unbounded ae using the fact that $\cos 2^nx$ and $\cos 2^mx$ are orthogonal for $n \ne m$ (and more generally any $k$ distinct such are orthogonal since for $n_1<n_2<..n_k, \pm 2^{n_1} \pm 2^{n_2}..\pm 2^{n_k} \ne 0$)

Answer (score -1):

Clearly, $\mathscr F$ is one-to-one, and hence, if it were onto, then by virtue of the Open Mapping Theorem, it would be a homeomorphism.

Comment: Sure. Then, what breaks down?